# Why cant I add text and delete it in the same if else?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to programming, so bear with me if I don't understand your explanation or if this is some common knowledge problem.

I'm starting a JavaScript/HTML/CSS course and decided to give my own spin to a line of code that was displayed on the screen. I think I understand the general idea, but I have no idea why what I typed didn't work:

My goal was that if they got the right answer there would be a green Ok, and if they got the wrong one there would be a red one. I didn't want them to appear at once though so I typed in a line that would clear the p tag of the wrong one if you got the right one and vice versa. For some reason, when you type the wrong answer the green Ok wont appear. Everything else works (from what I have seen) if you get it wrong the red Ok will appear and if you get it right it is deleted. The issue comes with the green Ok.

What should I do, and more importantly, why did this happen?

I also please ask if you are going to give a solution not to make it something overly complicated, as I will not understand it. I remind you guys I'm a beginner.

```html
<script>

function reply()
{
var answer = document.getElementById("questionPrompt").value;

if (answer == "Ok")
{
    document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
    document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "";
}
else 
    document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
    document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>

<input id="questionPrompt"></input>

<p id="rightResponse" style="color:green;"></p>

<p id="wrongResponse" style="color:red;"></p>

<button onclick="reply();">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't have curly brackets after your else, so the compiler looked at your if else like it was

```
if (answer == "Ok") {
  document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
  document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "";
} else {
  document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
}
document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "";
```

since there was no curly brackets, only the line directly after the else statement was considered as part of the else. So, no matter what `answer` was, the `"rightResponse"` p tag was always set to blank. To fix it, you just need to add curly brackets for the else, so that the compiler knows to include both lines of code after the else as part of the else, as shown in the snippet below.

```html
<script>
  function reply() {
    var answer = document.getElementById("questionPrompt").value;

    if (answer == "Ok") {
      document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
      document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("wrongResponse").innerHTML = "Ok";
      document.getElementById("rightResponse").innerHTML = "";
    }
  }
</script>

<input id="questionPrompt"></input>

<p id="rightResponse" style="color:green;"></p>

<p id="wrongResponse" style="color:red;"></p>

<button onclick="reply();">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you this explained it perfectly!

Comment: @DefaultPeak no problem! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you so others know.

Comment: Sorry, this was back when I first used Stack Overflow and I didn't know that was a thing.